# Drawing route direction from 2 input string address on MapView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I'm currently doing a task like below:

- Create a ViewController contains the `MapView` and an `UIView` (contain 2 `textfields` that a user will input the address on).
- Drawing the direction route from 2 addresses (input by above textfields) on the Map View.

I found some tutorials that show me how to do it with routing, but mostly by drawing from the current location to some destination.
My concept is to get the text from the `textfield` and convert it into coordinates and do some delegate techniques.

Can any one can guide me on how to solve it?

Comment: did you use swift 2.0 ? or use swift 3.0 ? and mention this in your question

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/87008/overlay-views-mapkit-swift-tutorial ??

Comment: Try my code you will get a latitude and longitude from your location that you want to pass.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the geo-reverse coding with convert your city name to a coordinate.

```
geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(currentLocation, completionHandler: {
            placemarks, error in

                if error == nil && placemarks.count > 0 {
                    self.placeMark = placemarks.last as? CLPlacemark
                    self.adressLabel.text = "\(self.placeMark!.thoroughfare)\n\(self.placeMark!.postalCode) \(self.placeMark!.locality)\n\(self.placeMark!.country)"
                    self.manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
                }
            })
```

This is the tutorial for drawing line between path coordinates.
https://github.com/varshylmobile/MapManager

Answer (score 0):

```
let address : CLLocationCoordinate2D = self.getLocation(String(Anand Nagar, Rustambaug Road, Surat, India, 395006)) 
print(address.latitude)
print(address.longitude)

func getLocation(address: String) -> CLLocationCoordinate2D {

        var center : CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
        let esc_addr: String = address.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        let req: String = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=\(esc_addr)"
        let responseData: NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: req)!)!
        var _: NSError
        var responseDictionary: [NSObject : AnyObject] = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options: [] ) as! [NSObject : AnyObject]
        var results: [AnyObject] = (responseDictionary["results"] as! [AnyObject])
        if results.count > 0 {
            var firstItem: [NSObject : AnyObject] = (results[0] as! [NSObject : AnyObject])
            var geometry: [NSObject : AnyObject] = ((firstItem["geometry"] as! [NSObject : AnyObject]) )
            var location: [NSObject : AnyObject] = ((geometry["location"] as! [NSObject : AnyObject]) )
            print(location)
            let lat = location["lat"]
            let lng = location["lng"]
            center.latitude = lat as! CLLocationDegrees
            center.longitude = lng as! CLLocationDegrees
            print(center)
           return center
        }
        else {
            center.latitude = 0
            center.longitude = 0
            return center
        }
  }
```

**Output :**

21.2173191

72.8664716